# server side processing and data: null columns

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using dataTables.net 1.10.19 have the following options set

```
ajax: "{{ route('admin.users.get') }}",
          columns: [
              { name: 'name', orderable: true, sortable: true, searchable:true },
              { name: 'email' },
              { defaultContent: "button", name: "action", data: "null", orderable: false, searchable: false }
          ],
```

But when the code is executed the null data column is passed to the server resulting in the error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'action' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id`, `name`, `email`, `action` from `users` order by `name` asc limit 10 offset 0)

The **action** column is suppose to be an ordinary column that has no data for it. If I remove the setting in the columns array though. The ajax request returns with success but the rendering only renders for the two columns.

How do I omit the last option for server side but still render the row column on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

Use `data: null` instead of `data: "null"`.

See [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) or [`columns.defaultContent`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent) for more details.

Comment: For some reason...that did not work as well. I had since switched to something else. Thanks for he help